# Asking sign in to watch video stream fro Raspberry pi camera

Tags: pi-zero

when I'm entering the IP address to watch the live stream, it's asking for sign in. I tried many things to sign in but it,s not working what to do to watch the live stream?

Comment: You're probably hitting the wrong IP address.

Comment: i don't think so because as per the instruction I did but still it's asking

Comment: How do you try to watch the live stream? Where do you enter the ip address? Is there another computer involved? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: static IP for my raspberry pi zero w with the given number while my raspberry pi is running the camera.